# Android - OnResume inside onBindViewHolder in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've got an RecyclerView that lists articles, in each article/item in the `onBindViewHolder` I'm loading another RecyclerView for the comments and I need to update them when the user returns to the activity.

Is there a way to detect the activity `OnResume` inside `onBindViewHolder` of the parent RecyclerView?

Comment: onResume is a lifecycle method, onBindViewHolder is related to a recyclerview, the two don't really meet :) what you're looking to do is _updating_ the _adapter_ inside onResume

Comment: @a_local_nobody but I can't update the child recyclerview adapter from OnResume of the activity because it seems impossible to keep track what current item of the parent recyclerview the user is currently viewing. I guess there are no solutions for that without big workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have some data class for article which holds its details and comments. You pass this list to first recycler which in onBind is filling comment recyclers with data. If you have to update comments just pass list of articles with updated comments to article's adapter. It will trigger `onBindViewHolder` inside which you will have new comments. In code it would be somethings like this:

```
data class Article (
    val name: String
    ... other details
    val comments: List<Comment>
)
```

onBindViewHolder for Article's adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
    val article = getItem(position)

    // here you should submit list of comments
    commentsAdapter.submitList(article.comments)
}
```

and in Activity:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    //get new comments here and set it for new articles
    val newArticles = oldArticles.map { article -> it.copy(comments = newComments)}
    articlesAdapter.submitList(newArticles)
}
```

By the way it seems like AdapterDelegates would be even better solution to your problem. Read more here: http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/adapter-delegates

Comment: You mean updating the articles on parent recyclerview? If yes then this is not what I need, this way I would trigger the API to get the comments again. If it's not like that but still requires to have the whole new comment list then I don't have it ^^ I only have updated information for one particular comment id that is already loaded and that I need to update

Comment: I don't see a problem, you should hold state in viewmodel, and if only one comment is updated, then you update only one in your state i.e:
`val newComment = artciles.findOrNull { predicate }?.comments.findOrNull { it.id == idFetchedFromApi }?.copy( update it here as you need)`,
and then update comments for article in same way.

Comment: Ok I get it, putting the comments inside the article list so when onBindViewHolder is loaded again and there is a comment list then skip the API